# Backbone 1.1.2: 'undefined is not a function' for behavior that worked in earlier versions

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I am a novice to Backbone, and I am in the midst of migrating a project written using BB 0.5.3 to 1.1.2. In 1.1.2, I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

The relevant extracts:

```
reportGen = {
....
initialize: function() {
    var reports = [
        this.Views.Report1,
        this.Views.Report2,
        this.Views.Report3
    ];
    new this.Views.App({reports: reports});
}
};
```

and:

```
reportGen.Views.App = Backbone.View.extend({
....

initialize: function(reportList) {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'switchReports');
    this.reports = reportList['reports'];
    this.render();
},
render: function() {
    var i = 0;
    var reportList = {reports : []};
    _.each(this.reports, function(r) {
        var R = new r;
        reportList.reports.push({name: R.name, label: R.label, index:i});
        R.close();
        i++;
    }, this);

    var out = $.tmpl( this.template(), reportList  );
    $(this.el).append(out);

    // now render the default Report
    var defaultReport = this.reports[0];
    this.currentReport = new defaultReport();
    $("div#report-container").html(this.currentReport.render().el);
    this.afterReportRender();

},
....
});
```

When I run this in Backbone 0.5.3, or in fact, versions prior to 0.9.10, everything seems all right. I get the interface and behaviors I expect. But in versions 0.9.10 and thereafter, I get the aforementioned error.

I've looked at the contents of the report objects in 0.5.3 and 1.1.2, and I can access the same items (for example, the name of the report). But I do not know what has changed from 0.9.9 to 0.9.10 and beyond to cause the code to fail.

The error occurs on the line:

`var R = new r`

the same error occurs if I use

`var R = new r()`

instead.

The changelog for 0.9.10 doesn't have anything that seems to apply to my case.

Any advice?

**Update**: I am still considerably confused about what's happening. I feel that I must be missing something conceptually. Inspecting the contents of `this` at each level hasn't led me anywhere.

**Update 2**: I have created [plunk with the error](http://embed.plnkr.co/OTx9x95HBij8uNH8CKo8/preview), but the behavior is somewhat different -- this time, the error shows up, but I can see the report names in the drop-down. Still, there is the "undefined is not a function" error in 1.1.2, but not in 0.9.9 and earlier.

Comment: http://backbonejs.org/#changelog

Comment: Likely too be one of the 2 functions removed. Your code extract doesn't contain any though. Check your other code

Comment: Where specifically do you get that error?

Comment: @muistooshort I edited the post to explain where the error occurred. (I forgot to add that in before having to run somewhere.)

Comment: @exussum: I've checked the other code, and neither `make` nor `change` methods appear.

Comment: Are you sure that `this.Views` is setup properly when you call `reportGen.initialize()`? Are you sure that `this` is what you expect it to be inside `initialize`?

Comment: Sure but the error suggests that `reports` is full of `undefined`s so maybe you just have a sequence problem that didn't happen before. Tossing in some `console.log`s is a quick way to check.

Comment: @muistooshort When I call `reportGen.initialize()`, it's being done in a `<script>` tag:  

    $(function(){ reportGen.initialize(); })  

At that point, `this` appears to be `#document`, and as such this.Views is nonexistent. When I go into `reportGen.initialize()`, `this` is the reportGen object, and it contains the Views object.  

I suspect I am misunderstanding something.  (Reposted comment because I took too long in my edit.)